# My Font only Showing Bold in Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, fonts

So I'm building a site in Wordpress and my  font on my slideshow looks really bold in Safari (which I like) and looks much thinner in Firefox and Chrome. Can anyone help me out with this? I'm using the google font Raleway (bold).

The link to the page is here:
http://ardxmteam.com/ari/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Put a class (let's say *slidertext*) on the container or the link of that text and then add this tiny CSS:

```
.slidertext{
  font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Comment: I currently have an inline style in it and from looking at the Firefox "Inspect Element" option I can see that Firefox is reading "bold" but it's not displaying the same type of bold lettering. Here is the current code that I'm using:

<a href="callto:#" class="h2" style="margin-top: 10px; font-weight: bold !important;">
CLINICAL<br />
RESEARCH<br />
SERVICES
</a>

Thanks for responding in a kindly manner and being willing to help.

Comment: Hi @Daniel. Probably your h2 has different styles defined somewhere else with more priority. Please search for the h2  styles in your css file(s) and put the same font-weight for all of them.
If that doesn't resolve your issue, then it means Safari and Chrome might have an issue with that particular font-face.